# When to delete copy constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list

i'm building a simple Neural Network, i have two main classess: NeuralNetwork And Level. I don't have neurons since it's a simple feedworward with all units in a level sharing the same activation function.

I've organized my levels in this way:

Class NeuralNetwork has a vector of levels (not pointers, values.), for fast access them and every object of class Level has a pointer to the prec and next level, some matrixes and stuff.

The question which is more general is:
What copy/move constructors/assignments operators for a class organized as a double linked list like Level should do?

- Copy the entire structure following next and back pointers and returning the istance  of the just copied object.
- Copy the single level leaving the pointers next\prec to nullptr    returning a singleton level with just the copies of the matrixes ecc..
- Delete the copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] to illustrate your question.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure that no inconsistent object exists. The second option sounds like an inconsistent object, although you could go and add a bool "is_valid" or the like, but then again, why allow copy if the result is not usable. I'd do the following: delete the operator for now and implement it should you ever happen to need it (I assume by delete you mean make it illegal to use, not to delete the code). If not, why waste time writing it? Especially since if you delete it, your compiler won't accept a copy assignment that you did not intended to do. Saves you runtime and memory.

Comment: Whichever suits your purpose. The golden rule is that when the object is destructed you need to make sure it won't invalidate any existing object. Done correctly any of the options you put forward might be right. But the one where you make a deep copy of all the data will probably suit any experimental model but may prove to have a performance overhead in any big production environment.

Answer (score 1):

What your class does is up to you. With that said, people will generally expect generic containers such as linked lists to be copyable.

When designing such classes, more generally, ask yourself the following:

- What does copying this class mean?
- Does it make sense to copy this class?
- Will user's be surprised if this class is copied?

If it's not clear what copying this class means, don't make it copyable. If it doesn't mean sense to copy this class, don't make it copyable. If people will be surprised to see the class getting copied (think unique_ptr), don't make it copyable without some serious thought. These aren't hard rules, these are just some thinking points to help you work out what's appropriate.

If you don't intend to make something copyable, it does indeed make sense to delete the associated operators (this acts as documentation if nothing else).

If you do make your class copyable, then it's up to you on how you implement it. You can make shared instances that copy on write, you can eagerly copy, you can do whatever you want; it all depends on what you your users (including you) will expect to happen, and what the trade-offs are for each.

Answer (score 0):

"Class NeuralNetwork has a vector of levels (not pointers, values.), for fast access them and every object of class Level has a pointer to the prec and next level"

That's a bit pointless. The previous layer is `*(this-1)` and the next layer is `*(this+1)`. That's because vector stores its elements contiguously. Of course, there's the minor challenge of knowing whether there *is* a previous or next layer, but that question doesn't tend to come up. The input layer is a special layer since you set its values directly. All the next layers can safely pull their input from the previous layer, so no layer needs to push its input to the next layer.

Training is a bit harder because there you have a backpropagation phase and need to walk in both directions. However, here you control both the inputs and the desired outputs, so you explicitly use `layers.front()` and `layers.back()`, never going past them.

Now, when you copy the whole vector, each layer is a copy and has a new `this`, but since the new vector is again contiguous the `*(this-1)` /  `*(this+1)` rule for neigbours still holds.